# Passing a type to constructor which expects a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

A typo lead me to stumble across some code which I do not understand. It compiles but I don't know why, nor what it is doing. Basically I end up initializing a class with the type as an argument when it should be expecting a pointer of that type instead). I've reproduced it below with a minimal example, could somebody explain what is going on here? Note that neither constructor appear to run. I'm also using `gcc 4.8.4, with C++0x (-std=c++0x flag)`.

```
#include <iostream>

class Arg
{
    Arg()
    {
        std::cout << "Arg constructor\n";
    }
};

class Wrapper
{
private:
    Arg* data;
public:
    Wrapper(Arg* _data) : data(_data)
    {
        std::cout << "Wrapper constructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper wrapper(Arg); //I do not understand what this line is doing
                          //nor why it compiles

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Wrapper wrapper(Arg);` declares a function which takes a single argument ot type `Arg`, and returns an instance of type `Wrapper`

Comment: Oh! Of course it does... How silly of me! It must be a Monday morning ;)

Comment: FYI, `Wrapper wrapper();` will also be a function declaration; a common mistake

Comment: I'm not used to seeing function declarations inside other functions so my brain just parsed it completely wrong. You wouldn't believe how long I've been scratching my head about this one... Thanks a ton!